# Using shiny in an interactive rmarkdown

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, interactive

I would like to make an interactive rmarkdown using `runtime:shiny` in the yaml header.

I load my single-cell Rnaseq data into a sparse matrix and make it reactive using the reactive function. But there is a problem because the data seems to be not reactive.

Below is the code I used:

````
---
title: ""
author: ""
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true
runtime: shiny
---

```{r init}
library(shiny)
library(Seurat)
library(Matrix)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(here)

selectInput('Sample', 
            label = 'Old or Young', 
            choices = c("old","young"))


matrix_dir <-  reactive({here(paste0(input$Sample,"/filtered_feature_bc_matrix/"))})
mat <- reactive({Read10X(data.dir = matrix_dir())})
renderPrint(dim(mat()))

```
````

When I run these commands, only the selection input is displayed. The renderPrint function no responds.

How to make it reactive?

Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

You would need to specify an output element to host that print, for example:

````
---
title: ""
author: ""
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true
runtime: shiny
---

```{r init}
library(shiny)
selectInput('Sample', 
            label = 'Old or Young', 
            choices = c("old","young"))

```

```{r print, echo=FALSE}
verbatimTextOutput("myprint")
output$myprint <- renderPrint(input$Sample)
```
````